# How do I check the time every second?

Tags: android, kotlin

The thread part was referenced from a piece of code written in java. I tried to convert it to kotlin the best I could with my amateur knowledge. Honestly it's probably the "translation" that's  making this not work but it was the only way I found to get it to run without crashing. Everything in the app works fine, no crashes, no errors,  nothing. It's just the textview won't change

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var listAdapter: ListAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        listAdapter = ListAdapter(mutableListOf())

        rv_reminder_list.adapter = listAdapter
        rv_reminder_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val popupView : View = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate (R.layout.popup_reminder,null)
        val popup: PopupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView, 1000, 750,true)

        btn_add.setOnClickListener {

            popup.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0,-200)
        }

        var calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val timeFormat: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a")
        var timetest: String = timeFormat.format (calendar.time)

        //********************here**********************************
        class TimeThread (): Thread (){
            override fun run (){
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted){
                        Thread.sleep (1000)
                        runOnUiThread(Runnable (){
                             fun run(){
                                temp_textview.text = "test"
                             }
                        })
                    }
                } catch (e: InterruptedException){}
            }
        }
        val timeThread : TimeThread = TimeThread()
        timeThread.start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 fun run(){
    //temp_textview.text = "test" 
    temp_textview.text = timetest
 }
```

It seems you do not set the right value for `temp_textview` textview.

In your case, I recommend using `Chronometer`

```
mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
mChronometer.start();
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer

Comment: I am trying to check the time constantly and when x time (where x is a time set by user when using app) is reached, do soemthing. I don't want to display an updating timer of some kind. Which is my fault because in my code it seems like that's what im trying to do but I was just trying to test whether or not the textview would update when I run the app

Comment: Move below code snipe into fun run() can help, but it will take a lot of memory usage

 var calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
val timeFormat: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a")
var timetest: String = timeFormat.format (calendar.time)